# Will search index Ajax content?

Tags: 2010, search, 2013, fast-search

I've got page containing a Data View Web Part. The page itself has been modified via SPD so that when loaded, jQuery loads up additional information (prices, etc.) for each row in the DVWP. Of course, this means that javascript has to be working, jQuery loads up, etc. This works great via a browser, but...

**Will SharePoint FAST Search (SP2013) or lesser (e.g. SP2010 Search) index that content? If not, can it be taught to do so?**

I do realize it requires the search engine to process javascript, and to wait for those items to load up in the DOM.

Comment: I doubt the indexer processes javascript but cannot say definitively. What is the source for the data loaded by jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast Search (2010) will index javascript sites.
SharePoint Search (2013) will **not** index javascript.

References: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/sharepointsearch/thread/b2456e71-9308-43f8-8351-b013b5070cc5
http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2010/08/24/fast-search-server-2010-for-sharepoint-specific-indexing-connectors.aspx

Comment: I am beginning to believe that Microsoft truly hates their customers. I am accepting this as the answer, but seriously... It worked in 2010 but NOT in 2013 ?!?!?